# What does this bash code mean :(){ :|:& };:

Tags: bash

An assignment for a class is to describe in one or two sentences what this line means and does

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

From messing around with it it seems like the only part of it that works on its own is the `:|:&` part which displays a number and then displays an extra line after every future command entered.

Just running the line creates a constant stream of "bash fork retry resource temporarily unavailable" running as a background process.

Running it as root displayed the number again and then made redhat freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

> The following fork bomb was presented as art in 2002;[5][6] its exact
>   origin is unknown, but it existed on Usenet prior to 2002. The bomb is
>   executed by pasting the following 13 characters into a UNIX shell such
>   as bash or zsh. It operates by defining a function called ':', which
>   calls itself twice, once in the foreground and once in the background.
>   :(){ :|:& };: